# How to bulk set custom filed meta value as tags in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a million articles in my blog and they all have a custom meta-key named `fromname_value`

and I want to automatically turn this field into the corresponding article tag.

I add some code in `function.php`

```
function my_migration_script()
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Quick and dirty way to get post ids. Normally don't use this method.
    $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post'");

    // Loop through all ids.
    foreach ($post_ids as $post_id) {

        // Grab the location meta value if it exists.
        if ($value = get_post_meta($post_id, 'fromname_value', true)) {

            // Remove any commas since it's used as a delimiter.
            $value = str_replace(',', '', $value);

            // Create a tag based on the `location` custom field value.
            wp_add_post_tags($post_id, $value);
        }
    }

    // Uncomment if you'd rather delete without verifying first.
    // $wpdb->delete( $wpdb->postmeta, array( 'meta_key' => 'location' ) );
}

// Kick off the script.
my_migration_script();
```

But this function will make the whole process super slow and will prompt 502 error.

I also installed plugin: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-taxonomy-meta/

However, this plugin will not be displayed in the menu bar of the website background management interface, and I cannot enter the settings page at all. I think the reason may be that this plugin does not support the latest version of wordpress I am using.

### Is there a more ingenious and efficient way to achieve this?
Thanks a lot.

ps:
All my post is from sql below:

```
use wordpress

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable ( col1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                            col2 bigint NOT NULL,
                            col3 longtext NOT NULL,
                            col4 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                            col5 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                            col6 VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL,
                            col7 longtext NOT NULL);
LOAD DATA INFILE '/www/wwwroot/csv/b-lengzhishi.csv'
INTO TABLE temptable 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;


    `post_author`,
        `post_content`,
        `post_title`,
        `post_excerpt`,
        `post_type`,
        `post_status`,
        `comment_status`,
        `ping_status`,
        `to_ping`,
        `pinged`,
        `post_content_filtered`,
        `post_date`)
SELECT  Postid,
        1,
        '',
        col3,
        '',
        'post',
        'publish',
        'open', 
        'open',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        col4
FROM temptable;


INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta`(`Post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`)
SELECT Postid,'fromurl_value',col1
FROM temptable;

INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta`(`Post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`)
SELECT Postid,'views',col2
FROM temptable;

INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta`(`Post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`)
SELECT Postid,'fifu_image_url',col6
FROM temptable;

INSERT INTO `wp_term_relationships` (`object_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`)
SELECT Postid,'7' 
FROM temptable;

INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta`(`Post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`)
SELECT Postid,'fromname_value',col7
FROM temptable;
```

Actually tags are in the `col5`, But I don't know how to write sql statement to import.

Comment: there will not be a faster method. instead of making this in php do it in the shell with a script which run till the end in the background and can run when the database has resources free

Comment: Do you have this plugin installed?  [_WP Index Improvements_](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Comment: Don't do things one row at a time; batch them.  Please provide the generated SQL so we can advise further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this plugin can help you:

https://wpsheeteditor.com/

```
With this editor you can:

Do all kinds of edits live on WP Admin. You can execute math formulas, remove thousands of duplicates, do advanced replacements, execute regex updates, and more

You can export all the fields easily

You can edit in Excel or Google Sheets
```

I never handled a dataset of millions but this can do things in batches and that would be better for not returning into 502-e

Hope this work for you!

Comment: My working environment is not very suitable for this plug-in, because the amount of data will be more, I experienced this plug-in, it will be very stuck.